# multiple subdomains pointing to same folder, but keeping the url

Tags: dns, subdomain

Is it possible to set up two sub domains and point them to the same folder, but keeping the url when accessing the site?

I have domains, one for business and one private, like this:

- private.tld
- business.tld

And I have created two sub domains like so:

- dev.private.tld
- dev.business.tld

  dev = development : This is where I test out new stuff and where I presents/demonstrate  finished modules.

Since they're both mine, I only need one single location for this. But when I share, I want to give the user the impression of they being either on my private or business development area.

All domains are on the same host and they're both add-ons domain to that account.

Do someone know how to get something like this scenario to work?

EDIT#1 : Just got to think of one thing; when I create the sub domains, if I point them directrly to the very same folder - would that do the trick? *(@work so can't test it out right know)* But would like to hear your thoughts on this...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You can point your VirtualHosts everywhere you want.

With NGiNX for example use *server* blocks
http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample

with different *server_name*'s 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

and *location*'s

Also you can benefit from reverse proxy mechanism:
nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/
(pass headers or change them on a fly, etc.)